# Installation of R package 'minpack.lm' had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, installation, package

I've been trying to install the R package minpack.lm on an HPC facility, but all I get is the following:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/lab85/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/minpack.lm_1.2-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 41287 bytes (40 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 40 KB

* installing *source* package ‘minpack.lm’ ...
** package ‘minpack.lm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c chkder.f -o chkder.o
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c dogleg.f -o dogleg.o
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c dpmpar.f -o dpmpar.o
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c enorm.f -o enorm.o
enorm.f: In function ‘enorm’:
enorm.f:1:0: warning: ‘__result_enorm’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       double precision function enorm(n,x)
 ^
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c fcn_lmder.c -o fcn_lmder.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c fcn_lmdif.c -o fcn_lmdif.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c fcn_message.c -o fcn_message.o
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c fdjac2.f -o fdjac2.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c get_element.c -o get_element.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c lmder.f -o lmder.o
lmder.f: In function ‘lmder’:
lmder.f:420:0: warning: ‘xnorm’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             if (delta .le. xtol*xnorm) info = 2
 ^
lmder.f:387:0: warning: ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                if (p1*fnorm1 .ge. fnorm .or. temp .lt. p1) temp = p1
 ^
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c lmdif.f -o lmdif.o
lmdif.f: In function ‘lmdif’:
lmdif.f:422:0: warning: ‘xnorm’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             if (delta .le. xtol*xnorm) info = 2
 ^
lmdif.f:389:0: warning: ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                if (p1*fnorm1 .ge. fnorm .or. temp .lt. p1) temp = p1
 ^
gfortran  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c lmpar.f -o lmpar.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c nls_lm.c -o nls_lm.o
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c prod.c -o prod.o
prod.c: In function ‘matprod’:
prod.c:55:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘FCONE’
        x, &nrx, y, &nry, &zero, z, &nrx FCONE FCONE);
                                         ^
prod.c: In function ‘crossprod’:
prod.c:67:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘FCONE’
    x, &nrx, y, &nry, &zero, z, &ncx FCONE FCONE);
                                     ^
make: *** [prod.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minpack.lm’
* removing ‘/home/lab85/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/minpack.lm’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmptxKRMN/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("minpack.lm") :
  installation of package ‘minpack.lm’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I install it on my laptop (Windows) it's all fine.

Any and all help appreciated.

I have tried installing the package locally but the download is not the issue.